# Find largest value of $n$ for condition to hold true

Tags: geometry, elementary-set-theory

Given the unit circle $\mathbb{U}=\left\{(x,y)\vert x,y\in\mathbb{R},0\leq x^2+y^2\leq1\right\}$, and a little bigger circle $\mathbb{U^*}=\left\{(x,y)\vert x,y\in\mathbb{R},0\leq x^2+y^2\leq1+k\right\}$,$\mathbb{U}\subset\mathbb{U^*}$, and a region

$$P_i=P(x_i,y_i)=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{U^*}\vert(x_i,y_i)\in\mathbb{U},(x-x_i)^2+(y-y_i)^2\leq k^2\right\}$$
for $0<k\le\frac{1}{2}$
and
$$d(P_i,P_j)=\sqrt{(x_i-x_j)^2+(y_i-y_j)^2}$$

Find the largest value of $n$ in function of $k$ if

$$\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}P_i\right)\cap P_{n+1}\neq\emptyset\tag 1$$

$$\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}P_i\right)\cap P_{n}=\emptyset\tag 2$$

must both be true.

---

From (2):

$$(P_1\cap P_n)\cup\dots\cup(P_{n-1}\cap P_n)=\emptyset$$

That means

$$P_1\cap P_n=\emptyset\rightarrow d(P_1,P_n)\geq2k$$
$$\vdots$$
$$P_{n-1}\cap P_n=\emptyset\rightarrow d(P_{n-1},P_n)\geq2k$$

but I don't know how to follow from there.

Comment: In plain english you're looking for the largest number of non overlapping closed disks of radius $k$ having their center in the closed unit disk

Comment: @Gribouillis Yes, that's right.

Comment: I think you can get a first estimate by using an hexagonal tiling of the plane and drawing a circle of radius k at the center of each hexagon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd view this the other way round: given a number $n$ of disks, how large can they be, i.e. what's the maximal $k$? See [circles in circles](https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/cirincir/) in [Erich's Packing Center](https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/index.html) which lists $\frac{k}{1+k}$, i.e. radius of individual disks $P_i$ as a fraction of the circle containing all these disks, your $\mathbb U^*$.

The arrangement using $n=12$ disks is listed without proof. So although there is some evidence suggesting that the listed arrangement and the radius it uses is indeed optimal, we don't know that for sure. Or at least the author of that page didn't know that at the time of writing. Even if the case of $n=12$ were solved by now, I doubt someone has come up with a general formula which works in all such situations.

So you can't expect to have a simple formula here. You can hope to find some publications listing the fractions for several explicit values of $n$, some with proof of optimality and many without. If that is not enough, you will have to go for approximate solutions, without expecting optimality.

Comment: I'm not sure it's exactly the same problem because in this problem we don't need to pack the convex hull of the circles in a circle but the convex hull of their centers. I don't mean that it's easier...

Comment: @Gribouillis: Packing the centers in a circle of radius $1$ is the same as packing the disks in a circle of radius $1+k$, if each disk has radius $k$. You already mentioned in one formula that the points of each $P_i$ are contained in $\mathbb U^*$ as well.

Comment: Yes you're correct. His problem is the same as the number of disks of radius $k/(1+k)$ entirely packed in the unit disk.